# ArcGIS For Javascript 3.3 - Access secure REST layers without prompting user for credentials

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I have a .net web application that is using ArcGIS for Javascript 3.3

I want to access secure layers from the ArcGIS REST service without prompting the user to log in.

Is there a way to pass the credentials in the backend so the user doesn't have to?

Comment: Do you have access to Portal?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a proxy. This configures the application so that all requests to  ArcGIS server for those layers will go through the proxy application, which can then securely pass credentials to the map service and then pass the data back to the map.

See [Using the proxy](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/ags_proxy.html) in the documentation.